# passing values to arguments - awk

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, grep

I'm executing the following `awk` command:

```
egrep '^[0-9]' /etc/hosts | grep -v 127.0.0.1 \
        | awk 'NR==1{ips=$1} 
                NR>1{ips=ips ", " $1} 
                $2=="namenode"{nn=$1} 
                END{ printf "/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C %s -Z %s -N mycluster --create-user -D /dev/xvdb", ips, nn}'
```

And returns the correct output:

```
/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C 10.224.43.50, 10.40.235.23 -Z 10.40.235.23 -N mycluster --create-user -D /dev/xvdb
```

Now I get smarter and try to follow the pattern:

```
egrep '^[0-9]' /etc/hosts | grep -v 127.0.0.1 \
        | awk 'NR==1{ips=$1} 
                NR>1{ips=ips ", " $1} 
                $2=="namenode"{nn=$1} 
                END{ printf "/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C %s -Z %s -RM %s -HS %s -N mycluster --create-user -D /dev/xvdb", ips, nn, nn, nn}'
```

That's it, I added two more entries with the same value of `nn` but I got nothing back. Why is that?

Here's a sample of `/etc/hosts`:

```
root@ip-10-40-235-23:~# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts

## vagrant-hostmanager-start
10.224.43.50    dgnode dgnode.dg.local
10.40.235.23    namenode namenode.dg.local
## vagrant-hostmanager-end
```

Comment: There is no obvious reason for the failure to get output from the modified script; you should get something, even if it is not exactly what you wanted.  Are you sure you're running it against the correct file?  Neither `printf()` includes a newline at the end; is that a factor in your problem?  Running your scripts against the hosts file you supply (not using my `/etc/hosts`) gets plausible results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the unnecessary greps and pipes and write it as:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^[0-9]/ && !/127\.0\.0\.1/ {
    ips = (ips ? ips ", " : "") $1
    if ($2=="namenode") {
        nn = $1
    }
}
END {
    printf "/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C %s -Z %s -RM %s -HS %s -N mycluster --create-user -D /dev/xvdb\n", ips, nn, nn, nn
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C 10.224.43.50, 10.40.235.23 -Z 10.40.235.23 -RM 10.40.235.23 -HS 10.40.235.23 -N mycluster --create-user -D /dev/xvdb
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried both of your command pipelines and getting output in both. Second command pipeline is also not producing blank output as you mentioned in question.

However you can make `awk` do all the work and remove `egrep` completely from your command:

```
awk '/127\.0\.0\.1/ || !/^[0-9]/{next}
     !ips{ips=$1; next}
     {ips=ips ", " $1}
     $2=="namenode"{nn=$1} 
     END{ printf "/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C %s -Z %s -RM %s -HS %s -N mycluster --create-user -D /dev/xvdb", ips, nn, nn, nn
    }' /etc/hosts
```

Comment: True, so an up-vote, but not an explanation of why there is no output in the second script in the question.

Comment: anubhava in your code looks like there's a escape problem somewhere:  `namenode: ERROR: Unrecognized parameter:  MyCluster`

Comment: Actually this us the copy paste of awk command that worked for me. But I will try it one more time once I get back to my computer as I am on mobile at present.

Comment: **Update:** I tried this command and it worked with your hosts file.

Comment: So I'm running that code through a chef provision. `==> namenode: Executing awk utility
==> namenode: /opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C 10.40.255.217 -Z  -RM  -HS  -N mycluster --create-user -D /dev/xvdb` has you can see only one IP address is making to the command

Comment: Hmm using above awk output I got it this: `/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C 10.224.43.50, 10.40.235.23 -Z 10.40.235.23 -RM 10.40.235.23 -HS 10.40.235.23 -N mycluster --create-user -D /dev/xvdb`

Comment: @philippe it's not possible for the posted script to produce the output you claim it does, even if `namenode` doesn't exist in the input file, since the script would print 2 blank chars between `-RM` and `-HS` but you are showing just 1. Beside that, though, everything points to the line containing `namenode` not existing in your input file so add a debugging `printf` to show when it should be hit. Also, I have no idea what it meas to run code `through a chef provision` - maybe others do, but if not maybe explain what that means as maybe the problem is there rather than your script.